# Was bedeuten "halb" und "scharf" bei Richtungsangaben?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Bei Richtungsangaben und Wegbeschreibungen findet man folgende Formulierungen:

> An der nächsten Kreuzung **halb** rechts fahren.
>   Nach der Kirche **scharf** links abbiegen.

Was ist hier mit "*halb"* und *"scharf"* gemeint?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"halb links"/"halb rechts" means that you need to turn left or right, but at an angle of less than 90°. I'd say "halb rechts" is roughly between 20° to 60°.

The angles I provide assume that 0° is straight ahead: you deviate 0° from the straight line.

For example, if you come towards a fork in the road with one road going (almost) straight ahead and another one going slightly to the left, then you could be asked to go "halb links" at that fork:

[image: Fring Road forks left from Sedgeford Road west of Docking - geograph.org.uk - 436197]

<sub>([Nigel Jones](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fring_Road_forks_left_from_Sedgeford_Road_west_of_Docking_-_geograph.org.uk_-_436197.jpg) [[CC-BY-SA-2.0](http://www.creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], [via Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fring_Road_forks_left_from_Sedgeford_Road_west_of_Docking_-_geograph.org.uk_-_436197.jpg))</sub>

"scharf links"/"scharf rechts" means that you need to turn left or right at an angle greater than 90 degrees. I'd say "scharf rechts" is roughly between 100°-150°.

If you come from the far side of the image above, then you'd need to go "sharp right" in order to go into the street to the left of the viewer.

Comment: No, if you want to keep Joachim's system consistent, straight on would have to be 0°. 180° would be a u-turn. :)

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. 180° can very well be thought of as a straight line. To me the angle would be the angle at which to deviate from the straight line, so 0° would be straight ahead. Am I completely off? Should I rewrite my answer?

Comment: Some navigation systems say "leicht links/rechts abbiegen" instead of "halb".

Comment: @OregonGhost: *"Leicht"* is even more confusing :D

Comment: Note by the way that the difference between halb/leicht and scharf is only relevant when there are multiple possibilities. If there is only one way to turn right, it's just *rechts abbiegen*, independent of angle. It could be confusing to add unnecessary adjectives ;)